# Java - Calling methods in a nested class, specifically an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Edit: Solved, I wasn't using 'validate()' after adding components.

I have a GUI class structured something like this (this is a very basic representation of my code):

Edit: here's my full code

```
package source;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame 
{
    public String[] list1 = {"equation1","equation2","equation3","equation4", "equation5"};
    public JOptionPane opt1;
    private JButton custom;
    private JTextField[] tf;
    public HandlerClass2 itemhandler = new HandlerClass2();
    private JList list;
    private static int index = 0;
    private static int lastlistindex = 0;
    private JPanel buttonpanel;
    private JPanel buttonpanel2[] = new JPanel[3];
    private JPanel listpanel[] = new JPanel[4];
    private JPanel checkpanel;
    private JCheckBox checkboxes[];
    private SpringLayout layout;
    public Container contentPane;
    private JButton but;

public Gui()
{
    super("Physics Helper v0.1");
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    layout = new SpringLayout();

    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(layout);

    displayPortal();
}

public void displayPortal()
{
    Icon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button.png"));    
    Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button2.png")); 
    custom = new JButton("", a);
    custom.setRolloverIcon(b);

    buttonpanel = new JPanel();
    buttonpanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    buttonpanel.add(custom);
    contentPane.add(buttonpanel);

    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, buttonpanel, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, buttonpanel, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, buttonpanel, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);

    custom.addActionListener(new HandlerClass());

}

public void displayButton(String s)
{
    but = new JButton(s);

    buttonpanel2[index] = new JPanel();
    buttonpanel2[index].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    buttonpanel2[index].add(but);

    contentPane.add(buttonpanel2[index]);

    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, buttonpanel2[index], -5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);

    if (index < 1)
    {
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, buttonpanel2[index], 5, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    }
    else
    {
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, buttonpanel2[index], 5, SpringLayout.EAST, buttonpanel2[index - 1]); 
    }

    index++;
}

public void displayList(String[] t)
{
    list = new JList(t);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(8);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(new JScrollPane(list));

    listpanel[lastlistindex] = new JPanel();
    listpanel[lastlistindex].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    listpanel[lastlistindex].add(list);

    contentPane.add(listpanel[lastlistindex]);

    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, listpanel[lastlistindex], 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, buttonpanel);

    if (lastlistindex < 1)
    {
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, listpanel[lastlistindex], 5, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    }
    else
    {
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, listpanel[lastlistindex], 5, SpringLayout.EAST, listpanel[lastlistindex - 1]);
    }

    lastlistindex++;
}

public void displayInputValues(String[] p)
{   
    checkboxes = new JCheckBox[p.length];

    GridLayout gridlayout = new GridLayout(p.length, 2);
    tf = new JTextField[p.length];

    checkpanel = new JPanel();
    checkpanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    checkpanel.setLayout(gridlayout);

    for (int b = 0; b < p.length; b++)
    {
        checkboxes[b] = new JCheckBox(p[b]);
        checkpanel.add(checkboxes[b]);

        tf[b] = new JTextField("", 9);
        checkpanel.add(tf[b]);
        tf[b].setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    }

    contentPane.add(checkpanel);

    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, checkpanel, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, checkpanel, -5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
}

private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {            
        displayButton("Back");
        displayButton("Next");

        displayList(list1);
    }
}
```

My main method is contained within another class, and works fine.

My question is how can I call the "displayButton" method in the actionPerformed method? I've tried a few tips already, such as calling it with "Gui.this.displayButton("Press me!").

I have tested every other aspect of my code, and this seems to be the only problem.

I get no errors when I run the code.

If needs be I can post the full class, but I think this problem lies in trying to call these methods.

What's your opinion?

Comment: You are missing semicolon at end of displayButton("Press me!"). I guess it is typo.

Comment: "I get no errors when I run the code." - but your code doesn't compile...

Comment: If you fix the compile errors, it works for me (edit: if you add the handler to the button as per @DNA's recommendation -- 1+ up vote to his answer). I am thinking that your problem lies elsewhere in code not show, specifically here: `//more code to display JPanels containing buttons in contentPane`

Comment: I run your code on my end with some modification. I replaced ActionListener with Runnable. And passed instance of HandlerClass to Thread. called displayButton method from run() and it works.

Comment: `GUI.this.displayButton(String)` should work; but it does require you to instantiate HandlerClass and set it as the actionListener for some event...

Edit: oh @DNA beat me to it

Comment: You're not missing a call to `revalidate` or something, are you? (See weird API docs for `Container.add`.)

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't my full code, which contains a few more methods for adding different JPanels. 'revalidate' might be it (I may have tried to 'repaint'). I'm starting to think that using CardLayout would be better, thanks to @Jim S. The basic idea of my applet is to add lists and buttons to the GUI following inputs from the user. Should I still be using 'SpringLayout'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the method works fine, nothing fancy needed

You need to add an instance of your `HandlerClass` to a GUI control, such as a `JButton`, which will trigger the method when clicked. That is the whole point of `ActionListeners` (and listeners in general). For example:

```
myJButton.addActionListener(new HandlerClass());
```

A working example based on your code:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame
{
    public Gui()
    {
        super("Physics Helper v0.1");
        JButton b = new JButton("Press me!");
        b.addActionListener(new HandlerClass());
        add(b);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void displayButton(String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            displayButton("Press me!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Gui();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that's part of the question but you can then programmatically simulate a click by calling myJButton.doClick(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29

Comment: @assylias: you're right -- that's not part of the question. 1+ up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Adding/removing components in a Container at runtime is possible, but not necessarily good practice.  If you want to display different contents based on user selections in your GUI, consider using a CardLayout layout manager, which handles all the runtime details automatically.

Jim S.

Comment: Good recommendations, and congratulations -- you've just got my last vote of the day. Now I have to wait 7 hours. :(

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. Shame it means I'll have to rewrite the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work finely. You will have to addActionListener to a component.

Else

You could write the displayButton method within the Handler Class.
Then you would have to simply call the method as it is with access to the previous class's members.

Answer (score -1):

The quick and dirty option is to make the displayButton call static.

Then issue is more a design one than anything else.  I'd suggest you ask yourself why you want your action listener to call a method in the owning object.

Comment: For every problem there is a solution that is quick, dirty, simple, clean and wrong (apologies to H.L. Mencken).

Comment: @Brent Calling a method of the owner from an ActionListener is an extremely common pattern